# IE9.js causing script error in IE6?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-6

Ive been tearing my hair out over this one. Im using [Dean Edwards' IE9.js](http://code.google.com/p/ie7-js/) to make IE6 less of a nightmare. This is in my `<head>`

```
<!--[if lt IE 7]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/ie6.css" type="text/css" media="screen">
<![endif]-->

<!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ie7-js.googlecode.com/svn/version/2.1(beta4)/IE9.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
```

Then, i open an IE6 instance in IETester and get:

`An error has occured on a script in this page:
Line: 7
Char: 28214
Error: Invalid Argument`

Removing the IE9.JS removes this error (but breaks a lot more on the site). Any ideas? The site is here: [ryanballard.tk](http://ryanballard.tk)

Thank you

Comment: looks like an error in the included code - did you try to contact the author directly?

Comment: The odd thing is, if i go to Dean Edward's site (where iE9.js is included), it works find my end leaving me to think its an error in my page (somewhere?!)

Comment: Why does the URL explicitly include "ie7-js" in it, I wonder? Anyway it could easily be that something the script is trying to do fails because you've got some CSS it doesn't expect or understand, or that's actually not valid.

Comment: IE6, the dark ages - we buried support for that version a long time ago, any chance you can push back on supporting that version?  http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/134/should-i-bother-supporting-ie6

Comment: It might be an issue with `font: inherit`. Take a look at this and see if the workaround helps: http://code.google.com/p/ie7-js/issues/detail?id=307

Comment: @Pointy - You were right. It was the CSS. Its still very confusing though. Its *something* to do with Eric Meyer's Reset CSS im using. V2 breaks IE6, V1 is fine. Its not the html5 attributes either i hear you shout - removing the first reset section and leaving the html5 specific reset doesnt throw an error. Very odd. Ideas?

Comment: @Krazer - PERFECT! That's it. Thank you so much. Solved. Any way to vote the answer up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently, it's an issue with `font: inherit`. See the workaround [here](http://code.google.com/p/ie7-js/issues/detail?id=307).